# Rejoined Active Directory but No Data Restored just shared folders

Tags: data-recovery, windows-server-2008, active-directory

My clients computer crashed and I installed a new hard drive and Windows 10 Pro. I rejoined the computer to Windows Server 2008 domain. I know I'm connected to the domain because I see two shared folders (public and scanned folder) in file explorer.

In addition we also have a users folder stored on the server that holds each computers data for desktop, documents, photos etc. When I joined the domain the two shared folders appeared in file explorer but none of the users data for desktop, documents etc.

Do I need to do something to tell active directory to restore station12's data back to there computer? Or do I change the location for the computers folders (desktop, documents, photos, etc.) to point to the windows server where the users data is?

Comment: Are the users folders mapped to their SAMAccount? It sounds like they were mapped at a Computer level, which would mean that rejoining the domain, even with the same name will not necessarily tell AD that this is the exact same computer.

Comment: Hello Mike, if you don't mind me asking what is a SAM account? I got it fixed on my own. I ended up changing the folder locations on the pc to point to the server where the files where. Not sure if this is the best/correct way but its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have said, it sounds like each computer has a mapped folder on the server and the user data is saved there. If that's the case, rejoining the domain may not be enough to reestablish the link between this 'new computer' and the old 'station12'.

If you have file server access, the quickest way to fix this is to migrate the user data from the old station12 folder into the folder this rebuilt computer has mapped.

Comment: Hello Mike, if you don't mind me asking what is a SAM account? I got it fixed on my own. I ended up changing the folder locations on the pc to point to the server where the files where. Not sure if this is the best/correct way but its working.

Comment: That would work as well. SAMAccount is just the domain account that a users uses to log onto the computer.